# SQL not updating even after link (using PHP)

Tags: php, sql

I will explain all the connections first:

**"orders.php"**

I have a table in this file where I outputted the info using a foreach loop, Id like to just focus on the "SCHEDULED?" column however.

```
require_once('orders-claimed.vc.php');

<tr align="center" id="<?php echo $rowOrder['orderid']; ?>">
<td>
  <?php
  foreach($lstOrder as $rowOrder) {
  //access database table "orders" (snippet)


    if ($rowOrder['scheduled'] == 'YES') {
   ?>
   <button type="button" class="btn-success yes-button" name="yes" id="<?php echo $rowOrder['orderid'] ;?>">YES</button>
  <?php
} else if ($rowOrder['scheduled'] == 'NO') {
    ?>
   <button type="button" class="btn-danger no-button" name="no" id="<?php echo $rowOrder['orderid'] ;?>">NO</button>
  <?php
    }
   ?>
</td> 
</tr>
```

[image: 1]

**"orders-claimed.vc.php"**

this file is where SQL gets connected to the table, below is a snipped of the "NO" button (name="no" in orders.php).

```
  require_once($routePath . "_mc/Order.mc.php");
  $mcOrder = new Order_MC();

        if (isset($_POST['no'])) {
    $mcOrder->Scheduled_Yes($db, $orderid);
  }
```

**"Order.mc.php"**

finally here is where the SQL code is located.

```
<?php
public function Scheduled_Yes($db, $orderid, $scheduled) {
 $stmt = $db->prepare(
   " UPDATE order
     SET scheduled = 'YES'
     WHERE orderid = :orderid "
 );

 $stmt->bindValue(':orderid', $orderid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt->bindValue(':scheduled', $scheduled, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt->execute();
 $rowAffected = $stmt->rowCount();

 return $rowAffected;
}
```

[image]

- Supposed to be "NO" will change to "YES" in the database, on paper everything seems to be connected but the SQL does not trigger when I click the button. Am I missing something or did I do the connections to the SQL and PHP wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

CHANGES:

**"orders-claimed.vc.php"**

$mcOrder->Scheduled_Yes($db, $orderid, $scheduled);

**"Orders.mc.php"**

WHERE orderid = :orderid AND scheduled = :scheduled "

both still gets no effect even when the parameters and WHERE is called

Comment: You don't have `:scheduled` placeholder in a query.

Comment: There is missing a bit of javascript for your buttons to do something, no?

Comment: Your `Scheduled_Yes()` function should have thrown a `PDOException` as it is missing the `:scheduled` placeholder

Comment: Also you are only passing two parameters to `$mcOrder->Scheduled_Yes($db, $orderid);` but trying your function is looking for three parameters

Comment: updated based on suggestions in this comment thread

Comment: There isn't a "form" element in the snippets you post, and you don't tell us there is any Javascript to handle the click events. Without those things, you haven't wired up your HTML form to the PHP functions.

Comment: id like an example based on your statement. I have a separate code for updating information with the same syntax above. By clicking save, the user is able to update their info in the database. there is no javascript required so im confused why it wont work with my scheduled button.

Comment: your code is a totally mix of copy paste errors id say. public functions not in a class. foreach inside a td for a single value and outside the same variable assignment. no form for buttuns. bind params and not using them in sql. eather try to understand what you are editing or provide a error log.

Comment: I would suggest you to debug your code in **Order.mc.php**. Do `var_dump($db, $orderid, $scheduled);` before your query statement to check if you get proper values from your button click event.

Answer (score 1):

Magandang umaga (based on the currency type in your application's screenshot, assuming you're Pinoy);

You should try running your code without passing any type specifying parameters during binding process. If you want to make sure that these values are being passed as the expected type you could store them in typecasted variables then pass them to the bindValue method. You also should not leave unnecessary empty spaces before and after SQL queries or at least end the line with a semicolon (;) or you will eventually run into problems and if you haven't set your application/server to throw detailed error exceptions you might not be able to know what's going on.

I also recommend that you develop a CRUD class where you can access and pass the values as arrays through custom built select, update, delete, etc functions to minimize the possibilities of making errors. If you keep hard-coding database operations over and over again throughout your application it is pretty likely to eventually make errors.

So you could solve this by creating a database class and include it in your application base. Then call the methods wherever you'd like to use them:

```
<?php
class Database extends PDO {
  public function __construct($DB_TYPE, $DB_HOST, $DB_NAME, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS) {
    parent::__construct($DB_TYPE . ':host=' . $DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . $DB_NAME . '', $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    Database::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }
  public function update($table, $data, $where) {
    // Don't forget to sort the data by key with ksort function, so that they won't be causing you headache, just in case
    ksort($data);
    $dataKeys = null;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      $dataKeys .= "`$key`=:$key,";
    }
    $dataToSQL = rtrim($dataKeys, ',');
    $stmt = $this->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $dataToSQL WHERE $where");
    // Loop to bind data
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $rowAffected = $stmt->rowCount();
    return $rowAffected;
  }
}
```

So then in the order.mc.php, or wherever you'd like to include this function (based on the details in your question, I'm assuming this should be the right place):

```
<?php
public function Scheduled_Yes($orderid, $scheduled) {
    $db = new Database(DB_TYPE, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $postData = array("scheduled" => $scheduled);
    $where = "`scheduled` = '{$scheduled}' AND `orderid` = {$orderid}";
    $result = $db->update("order", $postData, );

    /*
    You'll have to store this within a variable in order for it to work healthy,
    because you're returning the affected row count in your method,
    so I included it in my code as well. If you didn't want to have
    the affected row information you could run this method just as is. So:
    */
    return $result;
}
```

Like I said, I recommend you to create an object class which will make it easier and more flexible for you to use create, read, update, delete operations throughout your application. Then you would have less worries about making a mistake during database operations.

Finally in the orders_claimed.vc.php file to call this function:

```
require_once($routePath . "_mc/Order.mc.php");
$mcOrder = new Order_MC();

if (isset($_POST['no'])) {
  $mcOrder->Scheduled_Yes($orderid, $scheduled);
}
```

There is no $db variable to be passed to this method. So that was also a major problem in your code as well. You probably should set your error_reporting on in your .htaccess file (or maybe you'd also need to edit your php.ini file) to get detailed error reports to debug your code before deploying.
I hope this can help you solve your problem.

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for the in depth tips, modified my code based on the suggestions here. you deserve the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your code is a bit confused, but here are something that I saw:

You are trying to pass a `string` value using `PARAM::INT` to bind on query. Try it:

```
<?php
public function Scheduled_Yes($db, $orderid, $scheduled) {
 $stmt = $db->prepare(
   " UPDATE order
     SET scheduled = :scheduled
     WHERE orderid = :orderid "
 );

 $stmt->bindValue(':orderid', $orderid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $stmt->bindValue(':scheduled', $scheduled, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->execute();
 $rowAffected = $stmt->rowCount();

 return $rowAffected;
}
```